# Android: How to sort/arrange applications in custom order

Tags: android

Basically i am from .net background and learning Android now. I just wanted to develop a small app to order/arrange/sort the applications in mobile with a custom order. Please help me. I just know Collections.Sort() can perform sorting operation in android.

Comment: You wanna show a list of application in your own app? Basically what you want to achive is having the same list that you find in "Settings -> Apps"?

Comment: Alex, I would like to know how to list out all the applications in my app and then your will set unique order id for each app. Based on the given number i would like to sort the Applications and fix it in the mobile...